# Is there a shape/axis specific equivalent of `tensorflow.not_equal()`?

Tags: tensorflow, graph, tensorflow2.0, equality, tensor

I have a rank 3 tensor of shape `(100, 257, 121)` that we'll call y_pred.

I have extracted one rank 2 tensor from this of shape `(257, 121)` that we'll call y_element.

Is there a method similar to `tensorflow.not_equal()` that will compare y_element to every other rank 2 tensor element along axis 0 of y_pred, and return a tensor of bools of shape `(100)`?

Calling `tensorflow.not_equal(y_pred, y_element)` does return a tensor of bools, but of the same shape as y_pred, suggesting it's doing something like comparing the y_element tensor to all 3109700 values in y_pred instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
y_pred = tf.Variable(tf.ones((100, 257, 121)))
y_element = tf.Variable(tf.ones((257, 121)))
y_element[-1,:].assign(tf.zeros(121))

tf.reduce_all(tf.equal(y_pred, tf.expand_dims(y_element,0)), axis=[1,2])
```

this piece of code is based on the method you introduced and it compares element-wise the 2 tensors on the axis zeros. it returns an array of shape equal to the first axis (100 in our case). every element of the tensor of rank 3 is compared with the tensor of rank 2. True is return if ALL the tensor are equal otherwise false

Comment: What does each Boolean value of the returned rank 3 tensor from `tf.not_equal(y_pred, y_element)` represent? If I `and` each element on axis=0 into a single Boolean as you suggested use of `reduce_all()` will do, does that actually represent that element being equivalent or non-equivalent to y_element?

I didn't mention it before so fair enough, but I can't use `y_pred==` because it's going to be a function in the graph, but `tf.equal()` will do the complementary of what I want I guess then right?

Comment: After some experimentation on the command line, this answer is very close to spot on, the only adjustment I'd make is that `tf.reduce_all()` should be changed to `tf.reduce_any()`. If y_element is made up of some zeros and some ones, and that y_element is made up of y_element and a bunch of same shaped tensors with all zeros, then `tf.reduce_any(tf.not_equal(y_pred, y_element), axis=[1,2])` will return a shape=(100) length tensor of all `True` except for at the index y_element appears at

Comment: any or all is only based on what you are looking for

Comment: My question was an equivalent to not_equal, and reduce_any is the solution to that, not reduce_all

Comment: Cheers for the quick and awesome answer either way!